# После смены ширины экрана element.width не меняется

Tags: javascript, html5, responsive, mobile-web

У меня есть статические заголовки и один фиксированный. Фиксированный считывает стили `CSS` статических заголовков и присваивает их фиксированному.
Но при повороте экрана мобильного устройства `element.width` остается такой, при какой страница загрузилась. Даже когда вручную менять ширину, значение все равно остается прежним.

```
    function resize () {
      var titleStyle = getComputedStyle(titleElem);
      fixTitle.style.width = titleStyle.width;
      console.log(titleStyle.width);
    };
window.onresize = resize();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, для начала нужно исправить ошибки  в функции. У тебя не определены элементы, ширину которых ты определяешь( простите, за каламбур). Например:

```
function resize () {
      var titleStyle = getComputedStyle(titleElem);
      fixTitle.style.width = titleStyle.width;
      console.log(titleStyle.width);
    };
window.onresize = resize();
```

что такое  titleElem элемент и где ты его получаешь? Дальше, откуда ты взял fixtitle? что это за элемент? как ты его получил, откуда?
Дальше, метод `getComputedStyle` не всегда возвращает реальные размеры окна ширину например , выосту. если к ему применить CSS transform: scale(...);
поэтому `let width = elem.getBoundingClientRect().width;`-- лучше, но этот  метод всегда вызывает  repaint и перерасчет всех элементов страницы;  в общем пример ответа следующий:

```
window.onresize = resize();
function resize(){
    let elemForResize = document.querySelector('somethingSelector') ;

    let widthOfWindow = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    // можно использовать document.body.clientWidth вместо Getbounding, 
    // но опять же scale не учитываеться
    console.log(widthOfWindow);
    elemForResize.style.width = widthOfWindow +'px';
}
```

Прошу заметить, что это пример, потому что в условиях вопроса нет точных данных что мы хотим изменять и измерять.

Comment: есть грубо говоря такой код

<body style="max-width: 600px; margin: auto">
<div class="fixed" style="position: fixed"></div>
<div class="static" style="width: 100%</div>
</body>
мне нужен скрип который будет елементу с класом fixed присваивать  ширину елемента с класом static. И при смене ширины и при повороте экрана на мобильном, динамически.